# How to prevent embedded visualforce widget in standard page layout from becoming misaligned with other fields on window resize?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, inline-visualforce, stylesheets

I have a visualforce page that I am embedding directly inside the standard page layout for the Products object. I am trying to make it look and feel like a native widget. I followed the suggestion here to do that: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/45610/49567

However, I'm having a bit of an issue: The width of the columns in the widget is not consistent with that of the standard field labels/values on the page.

If I resize the browser window, they become misaligned. Here is some screenshots illustrating this undesirable behavior ("product image" is the custom VF widget, "product description" is a standard field in the native layout):

Alignment when browser is sized just right (how I want it to look):
[image: correct alignment when the browser is sized just right]

Alignment when browser width is reduced slightly (not good)

[image: incorrect alignment when browser width is reduced]

Alignment when browser width is reduced even more (even worse)

[image: alignment progressively grows worse as width is reduced further]

Here is my Visualforce code (irrelevant parts truncated for brevity):

```
<apex:page standardController="Product2" extensions="ProductPhotosExtension">
    <apex:form id="photoUploaderForm">
        <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem labelStyle="display:none;" dataStyle="display:none;">
                    <apex:outputText>&nbsp;</apex:outputText>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Product Image" for="fileImageId"/>
                    <apex:inputFile id="fileImageId" value="{!fileBody}"
                                    filename="{!fileName}" onchange="uploadFile(event);"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:actionFunction name="callUploadMethod" action="{!upload}"/>      
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

NOTE: I have the VF widget set to 100% width and 50 pixel height

Comment: Consider using `columns="1"` since you're not actually using a second column.

Comment: I tried that, but that actually causes even worse alignment issues. That is why I was using 2 as suggested in the answer I linked in my post. For reference, here's what it looks like if I set the columns attribute to 1: https://imgur.com/FPXQ17V

Comment: Well, it depends on how small you're making the window. The style sheets of classic are not "responsive", so they don't react well to limited space. You might consider using SLDS, so you'll at least get a consistent look.

Comment: Would using SLDS require switching my org to the "Lightning Experience"? Management doesn't really like it (and I can't say I really do either) so I don't really think that would be a viable option. Is there no other way to get the embedded VF page alignment consistent with the rest of the fields on the page? I think I understand why this is happening, since `<apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">` is basically meant to behave like the standard detail page. It's designed for a full page rather than an embedded widget, so it scales as the width of the widget is the width of the entire page

Comment: If there was some way to "trick" `<apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">` into being aware of the width of the actual page and not just the width of the widget, I think it would solve the issue. I don't really know off the top of my head how to do that though as it would probably require digging further into SF's stylesheets/javascript and and injecting the page width where the widget's width is being stored

Comment: It's just that the standard classic style sheets assume you have a minimum resolution (see [this topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browser_recommendations.htm&type=0)), so if you go much below that, you get odd behavior. I don't think there's an easy fix for this.

Comment: Well, I came up with a pretty ugly hack to sort-of fix this with some media queries. Still very, very far from ideal, but the widget still looks a lot better this way than it did before. I'll post the answer to reflect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've come up with a pretty ugly hack to (kind-of) fix this. I cannot stress enough, however, that this is a *seriously ugly hack* and it still isn't perfect as the elements aren't going to be perfectly aligned at certain window sizes (unless you add a crapton more media queries)

Some web developers may find the following code disturbing. Viewer discretion is advised.

CSS static resource file (photouploaderstyles):

```
.photoUploaderForm {
    width: 94%; 
    margin-left: 17%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media (max-width: 563px) {
    .photoUploaderForm {
        width: 155%;
        margin-left: 4%;
    }
}
```

Visualforce code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Product2" extensions="ProductPhotosExtension">
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.photouploaderstyles}"/>
    <apex:form id="photoUploaderForm" styleClass="photoUploaderForm">
        <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Product Image" for="fileImageId"/>
                    <apex:inputFile id="fileImageId" value="{!fileBody}"
                                    filename="{!fileName}" onchange="uploadFile(event);"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:actionFunction name="callUploadMethod" action="{!upload}"/>      
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```